# How can the NVidia driver 390 be used with kernel 6.2 (23.04 Lunar Lobster)?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, 23.04

**EDIT (prelude):**
*This question has been clicked for more than 1,000 times, but so far, no satisfying answer has been given. So there seem to be a tremendous amount of people who want this to be solved.*

I am using a Multi-GPU system with, beside others, two ASUS Nvidia GT520 graphic cards. For those, the NVidia driver 390.157 is the last one supported. It works ok (it has some minor issues) with KUbuntu 22.10 with kernel 5.19 on architecture x86_64.

Because of the GOP situation, I use the Intel IGP graphics adapter *UHD Graphics 750* to boot and use the GT520 as further display outputs.

Now my questions are:

1. How can I use the/an NVidia driver version 390 with the kernel 6.2 (23.04)?
2. How can I use the nouveau driver to make this work with kernel 6.2 (23.04)? *(If 1. is not applicable)*

So how can I make this setup work?
And could I upgrade to KUbuntu 23.04 flawlessly?
Or do I have to wait for future bugfixes (if they will ever come)?

*(The graphic cards do work ok for my needs, so I don't need or want to buy new ones.)*

**EDIT:

I am asking this question because others have had *this exact problem* before:**

- [nvidia-dkms-390 FTBS with linux 6.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/2009142)
- [390.154 driver no longer works with kernel 6.0+](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/390-154-driver-no-longer-works-with-kernel-6-0/230959)
- [Patch for the Nvidia legacy 390xx driver and kernel 6.2.x](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/12hfonl/patch_for_the_nvidia_legacy_390xx_driver_and/)
- [Nvidia dependency's prevent my gpu driver from properly configuring.](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=393627)

**This is not a duplicate for sure!** (checked it)
It is rather a generic question on how to support a specific driver for a new release version!

Comment: Have you tried it out?   https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: `nvidia-driver-390 | 390.157-0ubuntu5         | lunar/restricted            | amd64`  but you didn't specify architecture..  (*you could have run this enquiry yourself; I'm not running lunar either*)... If you want *opinions* on how something will run, you should ask on a Forum which doesn't consider *opinions* off-topic (ie. there must be a problem (question) to be solved - https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: No, no and no! Trying it out is not an acceptable option. I asked this question to get _experiences of other users_ and not _opinions_. Therefore this question cannot be _opinion based_, because the answer should be _experience based_. A major difference. I did try this upgrade some month ago which totally trashed my system. You are just trying to dismiss this question without further knowledge from the _Review Queue_. This **is a useful question for the many people using old graphic cards** with the new release (23.04) on x86_64 architecture trying to use NVidia drivers.

Comment: Experiences like *opinions* are off-topic here.. There must be a problem to solve (the question) with the answers addressing that. Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask  "*there is no actual problem to be solved*"   (this is a Q&A site and not a forum don't forget).

Comment: Reworded my question to emphasize the problem to be solved: **Getting the NVidia 390 driver version work with kernel 6.2 (23.04)**.

Comment: I can't fully answer your question, but I can offer a data point - the 390.157 driver failed for me after upgrading to 23.04 from 22.10. I was able to switch to noveau, but lost Wayland in the process (X11 only).

Comment: @StephenRudolph: Thanks for sharing your experience/partial answer that 23.04 does not fully support the 390 driver yet. So an update seems not to be sensible atm.

Comment: @zx485 - I found an Ubuntu 6.2 kernel bug tracker for this driver: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/2019869. The bad news is that the author claims the "nvidia 390 driver is unmaintained." It looks like a fix is out for the in-development version of Ubuntu, but as I write this, the haven't released the update for 23.04.

Comment: My experience is the same with @StephenRudolph, I had to use noveau and give up on Wayland with kernel 6.2 (Ubuntu 23.04). The [bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/2019869) status is **Fix Released**, but from my own experience the fix (nvidia-driver 390.157-0ubuntu5.23.04.1) does not fix anything...

Comment: I can confirm too, the package nvidia-driver-390 version 390.157-0ubuntu5.23.04.1 does not fix anything for me on GTX 660M. The behaviour is the same it was before: just after the boot logo is shown briefly (perhaps iGPU is used during boot process), but after that it's just a black screen with blinking underscore in upper left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you all for your interest and support in this topic.**

Unfortunately there seems to be no further effort by NVidia for supporting the 390 version of the driver for kernel version 6.2.xx, as mentioned [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/kernel-6-2-x-and-nvidia-390-xx-problem-with-nvidia-gpu-passthrough-in-lxc/260190/3) by the NVidia moderator *aplattner*:

> The legacy release 390 series of drivers is out of support, [...]