# Black screen after installing nvidia driver-390 on ubuntu 23.04, Can only use the xorg while there's no problem on 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 23.04

I migrate from kubuntu 22.04 , i install ubuntu 23.04 but get black screen during boot up, i manage to purge nvidia , work fine on xorg... Nvidia driver 390 not compatible with ubuntu 23.04.

Acer aspire 4755G with nvidia 510 (hybrid)
Works fine with ubuntu 22.04

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Does this answer your question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1467477/32664?