# Drivers for linux

Tags: drivers, graphics

Where can I find drivers for gtx 750 ti for linux, I've already tried to find drivers on nvidia's website, and I cant find any. (update: 22.04.4 LTS)

Comment: Usually it a bad idea to ask driver question without giving any clues about you Ubuntu version. So it can't be truly answered. But usually you do **not** install drivers that are not included in Ubuntu's hardware stack ->Install additional hardware app should find it

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: if this version of the NVidia driver works with your kernel version is unknown. Proceed at your own risk.**

You can find the 64-bit Linux drivers on the [NVidia website](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverresults.aspx/73666/en-us/).
Current version is 334.21

Latest update promises that it added support for the following GPUs:

- GeForce GTX 750 Ti
- GeForce GTX 750
- GeForce GTX 745
- GeForce GTX TITAN Black

Comment: Don't know if that works. Usually, the drivers must be compiled against your kernel. My GTX750 is not officially supported anymore for newer kernels. Since the OP didn't mention his Ubuntu Version, an answer can hardly be given

Comment: Yes. You're right. I asked a similar question [about the 390 version some time ago](https://askubuntu.com/q/1467477/51957). Added a warning.