# My nvidia graphics card GT630 synergy edition not working on xubuntu

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, xubuntu

i have installed graphic drivers 535, but it says 390 version is supported. After installing 390 version drivers my pc doesn't boot properly.

[image: this is the error an getting]

Comment: Are those errors for 390 or 535? Did you uninstall the other version?

Comment: these errors were for 535.

Comment: What errors do you get with 390?

Comment: Then i got this error: snd_hda_intel 0000:00"03.0: HSW/BDW HD-audio HDMI/DP requires binding with gfx driver

Comment: Do you need sound over HDMI or do you have regular speakers/headphones?

Comment: Regular speakers but not connected to pc yet

Answer (score 0):

The definite answer seems to be that [the legacy release 390 series of drivers is out of support...](https://askubuntu.com/q/1467477/51957)
This has been my question regarding this problem. So ***every*** graphics card that is is only supported by the NVidia 390 series driver **does not work anymore with kernel 6.2.0 and above**.

I use the Nouveau driver - which *somewhat* works.