# Ubuntu gui not starting after installing nvidia graphics driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I'm a new ubuntu user. I'm using a 22.04 LTS version.
It was running pretty fine until I decided to install an nvidia graphics driver.
I have an nvidia geforce GT 610 graphics card. I installed the nvidia-390 driver from the software and updates application then I rebooted. And now it just doesn't work
The boot ubuntu logo looks fat as if I'm running on safe graphics mode
[ubuntu logo at boot being fat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRAfO.jpg)

And when it's supposed to start the login screen it's just stuck in a black screen with an underscore.

I tried loads of solutions like running "sudo dpkg --configure -a",
Try going back to nouveau driver, reinstalling ubuntu-desktop etc.
But nothing gets it recovered

Comment: This depends heavily on your kernel version. I do not know if the current 22.04 kernel supports the 390 driver version. See my posting here: [How can the NVidia driver 390 be used with kernel 6.2 (23.04 Lunar Lobster)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1467477/51957). TL;DR: NVidia 390 driver is discontinued.

Comment: Boot, Hit ESC **once** as the "BIOS" text appears, you should get a "grub menu" where "advanced" leads to "recovery" options. run the fsck and network options then drop to a root shell and do `dpkg -l | grep -E ^ii.*nvidia` and uninstall the displayed packages with `apt purge <packagename>`, then do `reboot`